# How to connect to EKS Fargate instance from local machine

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssh, amazon-eks, aws-fargate

I have AWS EKS cluster with Fargate profile.
The cluster is in private subnets, and in VPC, which is not public.
I can use AWS cli from local machine, and I'd like to connect to Fargate instance from local machine.

Comment: Try this - 
https://medium.com/ci-t/9-steps-to-ssh-into-an-aws-fargate-managed-container-46c1d5f834e2

Comment: @ShobitJain, thank you. I've seen it, but it seemed quite complicated )

Comment: Help me to understand your query in a better way. 
Do you want to connect to the container deployed inside the Fargate Profile ?